# Guidance on building an au pair-to-family networking site

Tags: html, cms, social-media, business

I'm building a website for an au pair agency business that will connect au pairs to families around Europe.
I know nothing about website building, HTML etc. so I'm using a wysiwyg editer (weebly).
How I would like the site to function:

- Families upload their information into profiles
- Au pairs do the same
- families can view a limited part of an au pairs' profile until they pay a deposit
- After deposit is payed, all au pairs' profile information becomes open to families
- Families can order au pairs and confirm their order with another payment
- payment must be made before 'order' is confirmed
- By 'order' I mean full communications become open between the family and the au pair they have 'ordered' as well as travel information being sent to another agency
- the site needs to be linked with a bank account (e.g paypal) and another agency, who will look after the flight bookings etc.

A website already exists for this business however it just contains information on the business and application forms - if the site becomes fully automated it will relieve a lot of strain on administration in the office (dealing with applications, travel information etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly suggest outsourcing it to a programmer if you know nothing about programming or building a website. You can design the layout and build the template using your wysiwyg editor, but to get this functionality you'll have to dig into the code.

That said, if you are intent on building it yourself, I'd recommend checking out the Symfony framework for php. They have set's of "24 hour" tutorials that guide you through the complete process of building a site from start to finish using the Symfony framework (check out the jobeet and askeet tutorials in particular).

http://www.symfony-project.org/

Good Luck

Comment: I agree with Joshak; you're asking too much of weebly. Weebly is mean to be a hand-holding CMS so you can build a pretty website without much technical knowledge. You're trying to put together a pretty sophisticated site with e-commerce and security features. I am not familiar with Symfony, but I second the recommendation to find a skilled programmer to help you assemble this project. Your idea is not for amateurs.

Comment: If you agree with him you should vote up his answer